# Xamarin Android Player / Visual Studio: Stuck at "Starting Emulator"

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

Using Visual Studio and Xamarin Android Player (XAP), I suddenly cannot get my app to deploy to the emulated device. The whole debug process gets stuck attempting to start the device and, after an hour or so, never gets any further. The emulator itself actually does start, and it runs fine.

Interestingly, when the device is running, Visual Studio lists it as an unsupported device, and will not even try to deploy to it:

[image: Visual Studio, Unsupported Device]

I have tried running this and other projects in Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio to no avail. I have also tried updating / clean installation of the XAP, VirtualBox, JDK, and Android SDK/NDK.

Any ideas on how I can get XAP to work again?

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in the newest Xamarin.Android version. The bug is caused by an emulator name having spaces in it.  The default emulator names all have spaces. The easiest way to avoid the bug is to rename the emulators in Xamarin Android Player so they don't contain any spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I couldn't get any suggested fixes to work, so I will just revert to an older Xamarin.Android for now.

Comment: @CaseyDeDore Today I discovered a better workaround for this issue.  I've edited the original answer with the improved workaround.  Hopefully this is helpful to you or someone else.

Comment: Thanks a ton... This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I Renamed the emulators but still did not work, I used really short names like N4. Any other suggestion?

Comment: This particular issue with XAP should be fixed by now.  If you cannot get XAP to run I'd recommend using the Microsoft Android Emulator.  I've switched to it after updating to Windows 10, where I ran into networking issues with XAP again.

Comment: XAP is deprecated. The last release was from November 2015. Please switch to one of the supported emulators such as the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, or the Google Emulator (with HAXM) from the Android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the problem, try going to configuration manager in the drop down that says Any CPU and make sure Deploy is checked for your app.

Comment: +1 This is the answer for me. I have gone from Xamarin IDE to the free visual studi edition and for some reason this was not ticked on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using vs2015 community + Win10 Home 64 + newest android player 64, they work fine.
The download link is included in this page: 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/